# Future incompatibility

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, dart, future

I extract data from the `Firebase` to make a `list` of `FLSpots` and try to assign it to `LineChartBarData(spots: )` but the incompatibility doesn't allow it.

```
static Future<List<FlSpot>> _getDataFromFirestore() async {

  ...
  ...

  List<FlSpot> spots = listData.asMap().entries.map((e) {
    return FlSpot(e.key.toDouble(), e.value);
  }).toList();

  // print(spots);
  return spots;
```

how can I assign it to avoid the error:
`The argument type 'Future<List<FlSpot>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<FlSpot>'.` when I try

```
LineChartBarData(
          spots: _getDataFromFirestore(),
```

Comment: you  should await for _getDataFromFireStore. You could use initState to load the data. And while the data is loading you show a loading indicator. That's the common approach for async data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it

Answer (score 0):

```
LineChartBarData(
          spots:await _getDataFromFirestore(),
```

use `await` keyword before calling the function.

Comment: No change, just throw me 'Unexpected text await.'

Comment: Use steam Builder if you are using firebase